# sphinx autodoc for python doesn't show anything (on readthedocs)

Tags: python, api, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have [this python package](https://github.com/neuropsychology/Neuropsydia.py) that I'd like to automatically document using Sphinx. I've inserted docstrings in every functions and classes.

I made an account on ReadTheDocs, and did the setup accordingly (i.e., a `docs/` dir with a `conf.py` file). Then, basically, I've tried almost everything: every combination of `autodoc::`, `autofunction::`, `autoclass::`; I tried using the *same* `conf.py` file as other packages which documented API (with specific changes made according to my case, of course); but it just doesn't work, the API page remains inexorably empty...

Comment: And if you go to the build page in RTD (`https://readthedocs.org/projects/<your-project>/builds/`), do you get any feedback there? How did you generate `api.rst`? I find this useful for initial setup: https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful link! However, even though I tried reproducing these steps and tried building up the documentation from scratch, it still doesn't show anything. Worst part is, when I run the makefile (using the command `make html`, it shows no particular error and nothing related to the package I'm trying to document...). I just can't figure out why! As to my `api.rst` file, it was generated only by creating a rst doc and inserting some `..autoclass::` directives. Anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: That might be the problem, have you considered getting Sphinx to generate the docs rather than trying to do it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your conf.py :

```
########### TRICK FOUND ON SOME TUTORIAL : ADD IN THE MOCK_MODULES ANY EXTERNAL MODULE YOU'RE USING IN YOUR PACKAGE.

import mock

MOCK_MODULES = ['numpy', 'scipy', 'sklearn', 'matplotlib', 'matplotlib.pyplot', 'scipy.interpolate', 'scipy.special', 'math', '__future__', 'toolboxutilities']
for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = mock.Mock()
```

In the MOCK_MODULES, add any single external import that your project uses. I had exactly the same problem and this solved it.

Also in the conf.py, don't forget to add the :

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

In your case you already have it but I mention it in case someone else with the same problem would see my answer.