# Python Sphinx autodoc not rendering on readthedocs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have a Python package hosted on Github called [spike2py](https://github.com/MartinHeroux/spike2py). I have prepared my docs using Sphinx and .rst files. These files are hosted on GitHub [here](https://github.com/MartinHeroux/spike2py/tree/master/docs). I am able to successfully run `make html` locally and obtain the desired output. That is, the Reference Guide part of the documentation contains the API automatically generated using the docstring I have included in my code, and referenced using calls to `autoclass` and `autofunction` ([reference_guide.rst](https://github.com/MartinHeroux/spike2py/blob/master/docs/source/pages/reference_guides.rst)).

For example, here is what the first part of the Reference Guide looks like when I render it locally:

[image]

However, when the documentation is rendered on `readthedocs` ([see here](https://spike2py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/reference_guides.html)), the Reference Guide does not contain the extracted doctrings; just the headers found in the .rst file.

**Expected behaviour**

I expected the docs rendered on readthedocs to be same as those rendered locally. However, this is not happening.

By looking [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/spike2py/downloads/), I have confirmed that the version being presented on readthedocs in the current version of my documentation.

But when I try to download PDF or HTML versions of the documentation, the Reference Guide does not include the docstrings.

**Other info**

According to the readthedocs [documentation](https://dont-be-afraid-to-commit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation.html#publishing-your-documentation), the local builds should not be pushed to GitHub; only the source files.

This is somewhat related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616447/sphinx-autodoc-for-python-doesnt-show-anything-on-readthedocs), but I was not able to make the proposed solution work.

**UPDATE**
I followed the solution recommended by Steve Piercy and this solved part of the problem. I added a `docs/requirements.txt` file as well as a `.readthedocs.yml` file.

Next I noticed that the build was using Python 3.7.9. Given that I was using type hints from Python >= 3.8, I had to specify the version of Python in the `.readthedocs.yml` file.

Then I was stuck with the RTD build telling me it can't find my index.rst file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/spike2py/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 280, in build_main
    app.build(args.force_all, filenames)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/spike2py/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 348, in build
    self.builder.build_update()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/spike2py/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 297, in build_update
    self.build(to_build,
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/spike2py/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 311, in build
    updated_docnames = set(self.read())
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/spike2py/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 421, in read
    raise SphinxError('master file %s not found' %
sphinx.errors.SphinxError: master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/spike2py/checkouts/latest/docs/index.rst not found

Sphinx error:
master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/spike2py/checkouts/latest/docs/index.rst not found
```

But I then solved this by specifying the following in my `.readthedocs.yml`:

```
# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/source/conf.py
```

After this fix, the docs are built with what appears to be no errors and includes the following:

```
generating indices...  genindex py-modindexdone
highlighting module code... [ 20%] spike2py.channels
highlighting module code... [ 40%] spike2py.plot
highlighting module code... [ 60%] spike2py.read
highlighting module code... [ 80%] spike2py.sig_proc
highlighting module code... [100%] spike2py.trial
```

And yes, the doctrings appeared on RTD.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64700797) gives some insights into what is happening with your build on RTD, although the OP in that thread used a much more complicated setup. Anyway, if `autodoc` is building locally and on GitHub but not on RTD chances are it's because the RTD build can't import your modules (I'm not experienced enough on that site to pinpoint a solution, but this is the logic you should search for - I hope a more experienced member can contribute their analyses of the problem.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your project's dependencies are not specified on RTD, but you have installed the dependencies locally.  You can verify this in the [build log](https://readthedocs.org/projects/spike2py/builds/12651916/).  Visit your project's Builds, click a build, and click "view raw".

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'trial.TrialInfo' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'trial.Trial' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import function 'trial.load' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'channels.ChannelInfo' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'channels.Channel' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'channels.Event' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'channels.Keyboard' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'channels.Waveform' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'channels.Wavemark' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'sig_proc.SignalProcessing' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import function 'plot.plot_channel' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import function 'plot.plot_trial' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import function 'read.read' from module 'spike2py'; the following exception was raised:
cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
```

To remedy the situation, you must specify that your project's dependencies must be installed.  See [Specifying Dependencies](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/specifying-dependencies.html).

You must either:

1. Create a [pip requirements file that specifies requirements](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-a-requirements-file), or
2. Create a file that specifies a `pip install` option which will install requirements that are already defined elsewhere, such as in a `setup.py` `docs_requires` stanza.  See an example in the Pyramid repository with its [rtd.txt](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/rtd.txt) and [setup.py](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/setup.py).

### rtd.txt

```
-e .[docs]
```

### setup.py

```
docs_extras = [
    'Sphinx >= 3.0.0',  # Force RTD to use >= 3.0.0
    'docutils',
    'pylons-sphinx-themes >= 1.0.8',  # Ethical Ads
    'pylons_sphinx_latesturl',
    'repoze.sphinx.autointerface',
    'sphinxcontrib-autoprogram',
]
# ...
    extras_require={'testing': testing_extras, 'docs': docs_extras},
```

One you have defined your project requirements in this file, then you must configure Read the Docs to recognize this file to install dependencies.  The preferred method is to use a [configuration file](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/index.html), but you can also do this through the [project's Admin Dashboard](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/specifying-dependencies.html#using-the-project-admin-dashboard).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue Steve. Your suggestion got me most of the way. However, as you will see in the update above, I am still having issues.

Comment: @MartinHéroux I just checked the built docs, and I see docstrings in the latest build. Is there still a problem?

Comment: All seems to work now! Great, and thanks. I guess I did not check the latest build...apologies, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. Readthedocs could not extract the docstrings from my Project because it did not find my project module.

I solved this by adding 2 relative paths in the docs/conf.py:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../"))
```

So that now the top of the docs/conf.py looks as follows:

```
import os
import sys
import sphinx_rtd_theme

    # If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
    # add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
    # documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../"))
    sys.path.insert(1, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("../")) + os.sep + "feature_engine")
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. I already had the path to my module specified in the conf.py file; if this is not specified I cannot build the documentation locally on my own machine. When I do specify it, I can build the documentation locally. The problem is that RTD does not render the docstrings. Also, why import sphinx_rtd_theme? If is not used on conf.py. And what does the 3rd sys.path line do in your suggested answer? Thanks again for looking at this issue.